# Perl regular expression PRXCHANGE in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I'd like some help with the following statements.

Im trying to merge 2 prxchange statements into one.

The purpose of the code is to change any non-printable ASCII characters into the corresponding 2-character hexadecimal code surrounded by double brackets e.g. [A0].

The first statement below changes hex character xA0.
The second changes hex characters in the range x20 to x7E.

Is it possible to combine these statements into one?

```
            var = prxchange ( "s/([\xA0])/[A0]/"       , -1 , varcontent);
            var = prxchange ( "s/([^\x20-\x7E])/[$1]/" , -1 , varcontent);
```

Comment: In PERL, complex replacements of this kind typically involve the 'subst' operator (s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/OPTIONS) with a `/e` option to indicate REPLACEMENT is a PERL expression that is to be evaluated in-line.  SAS `PRXCHANGE` does not implement `/e`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `HEX.` format to do this instead? Regex seems like a rather complicated way of doing this if you have SAS.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000205154.htm

E.g.

```
data _null_;
  length a b $32;
  a = '09400940'x;
  do i = 1 to length(a);
    char = substr(a,i,1);
    rank = rank(char);
    if rank < 32 then b = cats(b,'[',put(rank,hex2.),']');
    else b = cats(b,char);
  end;
  put a= $32. / b= $32.;
run;
```